# How to adjust delay of suggestion list in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, autosuggest

In python 3.3.2, how you adjust the time it takes for the suggestion box to appear just after typing a '.'. For example, say I import wxPython and type `wx.` after 3 seconds a list box would appear showing the available options. Is there any way to set this to appear instantly or in a very short time? Sort of like Visual Studio's intellisense feature which appears instantly.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to your IDE, the editor you are using to write your code. If this is the case, that would depend on your editor, which one are you using?

If you are using the built-in editor IDLE, then what you are looking to do is not an available option.

If you are trying to do this within your own code using wxPython (as 
SexySaxMan suggested), please provide an example of your code so we can get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was referring to the editor IDLE, sorry for not being clear. Is there any other editor that you know of which can do this?

Comment: I could not locate it in Komodo IDE either, you can try some of the ones listed here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors, unless someone else has a better suggestion?

Comment: Let me correct myself, Komodo IDE or Komodo Edit have suggestion popups that load relatively quick, although some modules take longer to load the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is something like time.sleep
http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep

EDIT: I haven't really used wxPython, but I have used Tkinter and Tkinter.after does exactly what you're asking for. Try looking for a parallel in wxPython.